# Group by and multiply columns with a shift in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with different companies price history and a dividend adjustment factor in the dataframe `df`.
I want to calculate the adjusted close price (which considers the dividend adjustment factor) for each company.
I tried some variations of
`df['Adj Close'] = df.groupby('companyName')['priceUSD']*df['divAdjFactor'].shift(1)`

Picture of a snippet of my original dataframe (non-grouped) and a test view of a filtered frame where I apply the calculation as I want. In the second frame I multiplied 0.595318 with 36.48 (just so happens here the first two `divAdjFactor` are there same, not always the case). I want to do this calculation on the original dataframe.

```
testlist = ['General Electric Company']
df_adj = df.query('companyName == @testlist')
df_adj['Adj Close'] = df_adj['priceUSD'] * df_adj['divAdjFactor'].shift(1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) per `divAdjFactor`:

```
df['Adj Close'] = df['priceUSD']*df.groupby('companyName')['divAdjFactor'].shift(1)
```